# How to "webscrape" a site containing a popup window, using python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, code-contracts, etherscan

I am trying to web scrape a  certain part of the etherscan site with python, since there is no api for this functionality. Basically going to [this link](https://etherscan.io/proxyContractChecker?a=0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48) and one would need to press verify, after doing so a popup comes up which you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2zP8.png). What I need to scrape is this part `0x0882477e7895bdc5cea7cb1552ed914ab157fe56` in case the message starts with the message as seen in the picture.

I've written the below python script that starts this off, but I don't know how it's possible to interact further with the site, in order to have that popup come to the foreground and scrape the information. Is this possible to do?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import get

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0','X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',}
url = "https://etherscan.io/proxyContractChecker?a=0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48"
response = get(url,headers=headers )
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content,'html.parser')
```

Thank You

Comment: Check out [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html#interacting-with-the-page) or [webbrowser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html) @KALEB

Comment: Just to clarify, I know if you work this with Selenium or Scrapy it will work. However, is achievable with Beautiful Soup and Requests lib

Comment: I'm agnostic to the package, as long as it's in python... it'll check out the scrapy library thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def Main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        r = req.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Ahmed American :)'})
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
        vs = soup.find("input", id="__VIEWSTATE").get("value")
        vsg = soup.find("input", id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR").get("value")
        ev = soup.find("input", id="__EVENTVALIDATION").get("value")
        data = {
            '__VIEWSTATE': vs,
            '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR': vsg,
            '__EVENTVALIDATION': ev,
            'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtContractAddress': '0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48',
            'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnSubmit': "Verify"
        }
        r = req.post(
            "https://etherscan.io/proxyContractChecker?a=0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48", data=data, headers={'User-Agent': 'Ahmed American :)'})
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
        token = soup.find(
            "div", class_="alert alert-success").text.split(" ")[-1]
        print(token)


Main("https://etherscan.io/proxyContractChecker")
```

Output:

```
0x0882477e7895bdc5cea7cb1552ed914ab157fe56
```

Comment: Man thanks a lot !!! appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with @InfinityTM. Usually the workflow that is follow for this kind of problems is that you will need to make a POST request into the website.

Look, if you click on **Verify** a POST request is made into the website as shown in this image:

[image: After Verify was clicked]

This **POST** request was made with this **headers**:

[image: Request Headers]

and with this **params**:

[image: Params]

You need to figure out how to send this **POST** request with the correct URL, headers, params, and cookies. Once you have achieved to make the request, you will receive the **response**:

[image: Response]

which contains the information you want to **scrape** under the **div with class "alert alert-success**:

**Summary**

So the steps you need to follow are:

1. Navigate to your website, and gather all the information (request URL, Cookies, headers, and params) that you will need for your **POST** request.
2. Make the request with the **requests** library.
3. Once you get a <200> response, **scrape** the data you are interested in with BS.

Please let me know if this points you in the right direction! :D

Comment: Good work. New to me. May pros said it ain't possible.

Comment: Let me know if you progress with this task if you get stuck at some point, I will be happy to help you :D

Comment: @EnriqueBet where the answer itself ? where the code ? show me your code and the output to the `OP`

Comment: I believe that the person that is working with the project should perform the first attempt after pointing in the right direction. I will be working on the code for this in the meanwhile.

Comment: @EnriqueBet thank you for your helpful post, I'll try it out... and sure will keep you posted

Comment: FYI it’s __scrape__ not scrap